# What X-Men comic features Storm being attacked by a group of drug addicts in a housing project, and is saved by Luke Cage and Misty Knight?

Tags: story-identification, marvel, comics, x-men

**Plot Details/Summary**

I don't remember the entire storyline from the issue, but I do have pretty good details on the scene I'm trying to remember.

Storm is in Harlem, I believe, and she's wandered in to a housing project.  I can't remember exactly why, just that she does so.  She comes upon a room filled with teens and early 20-somethings who are all strung out on drugs.   The leader of the pack becomes very aggressive with her, and after she tries to explain herself, he slashes her hand with a knife he had been concealing.  I recall Storm shouting "MY HAND!!!" and in the next frame saying something about the blade cutting her to the bone.

To defend herself, she conjures up a wind storm inside the room, tossing the attacking addicts about.  She thinks to herself something about not wanting to hurt them, as they were just children (even if they were dangerous)"   She's so involved in thought, she doesn't notice the creep who slashed her hand is now creeping up behind her and intent on plunging the knife in her back.

A yellow-sleeved arm shoots out from behind the knife-wielding guy, grabbing him by the wrist along with the words "Uh-UH, punk." It's Luke Cage and he slams the other guy into a nearby wall.

It turns out Cage and Misty Knight had gotten word that an unusual woman had been seen uptown, and they figured it was her.  Storm, not being as streetwise as the others, asks how these kids could have gotten this way, and why isn't something done about it?   Cage responds with something along the lines of these kids having no hope, no future, and the politicians just want to ignore it.  Something like that.

**Publication Details/Timeframe**

I'd guess this particular issue came out in the late 70s to very early 1980s.  It *might* have been part of a greater storyline where the X-Men were looking for young mutants who were in trouble or something, but I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's actually [Uncanny X-Men #122](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/X-Men_Vol_1_122) from 1979.  If #544 includes the pages posted in @Valorum's answer it's a re-print.

> Entering an old apartment building where her parents used to live, Storm is surprised to find that it is now an abandoned tenement and a junkie shooting gallery. When the junkies squatting there assault her, she uses her weather powers to fight back. One of them sneaks behind her and is ready to stab her but is subdued by Luke Cage, who is accompanied by Misty Knight.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! Can you provide some evidence that it is #122 instead of #544?

Comment: The link in the other answer does list "Storm (Ororo Munroe) (Recap)", so it's possible both answers are correct: the _issue_ is not a reprint, but the _panels_ appear in the final issue as a flashback to a previous storyline.

Comment: The synopsis for #122 [on the same wiki](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/X-Men_Vol_1_122) also matches the described storyline.

Comment: While both answers are correct regarding the presence of the scenes/storyline,  #122 was the specific issue I was trying to recall from my youth.

Answer (score 10):

This is [Uncanny X-Men Vol.1 #544](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Uncanny_X-Men_Vol_1_544) "*The Trial of Colossus!*"

**Shooting gallery**
[image]

**Storm is cut *"to the bone"***
[image]

**Luke Cage turns up and beats up some punk**
[image]

Comment: Purely as a point of interest, issue #544 was the final issue in this series and frequently reprinted, hence why so many people seem to remember it.

Comment: So it's from... 2011?

Comment: It is not. That's Byrne art from his original run.